# how to enable SOAP,CURL,OPENSSL extension dynamically?

Tags: php, soap, curl, xampp, ini

i trying to enable SOAP,CURL,OPENSSL extension using ini_set() dynamically.what is the syntax to enable these above ext using ini_set()? i dont have permission to edit php.ini file.
thanks...

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The list of `ini` parameters and where you can change them is here: [List of *php.ini* directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

You'll see that the `extension` parameter is only configurable in the `php.ini` file.