# how to enable openssl with help of ini_set or .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

i have a problem in sending mail module in my site, beacause ssl is not enable.
so my question is it is possible to set `openssl` with `ini_set()` or `.htaccess`.
or any other way for enable openssl?

**NOTE**
i know the way of enable openssl with php.ini file. but i have no access of `php.ini` file.
the site is in share server.

Comment: Possible duplicate [how to enable SOAP,CURL,OPENSSL extension dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103735/how-to-enable-soap-curl-openssl-extension-dynamically)

Comment: follow the link provided, read the answer. Quote "you can't"

Comment: _“dude..i am trying to know”_ – well _dude_, then try _reading_ answers you are linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apache support for openSSL is not there it's also possible openSSL isn't installed at all. Regardless, this is a configuration directive exclusively and cannot be changed via any of the methods you mentioned.

Comment: in php info it only display `ssl support enable in imap section`

Comment: That means you can use SSL for IMAP connections.
Is mod_ssl even installed? Will show up in the `apache2handler` section of `phpinfo()`

Comment: also, there should be an openssl section

Comment: there is no `apache2handler` and `openssl` section in `phpinfo()`.actually it is a share server.

Comment: I would contact your host then. There's nothing you can do without config files here.

Comment: thanks..i contact my host and then they enable openssl for me.